# Change Radio Button Colour in Bootstrap 3 using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have some radio buttons:

```
<div class="form-group text-danger">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4 pull-left text-danger" for="SongTitle">Is a Remix</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="admin-form theme-primary">
                        <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 mr10 pull-left text-danger">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsRemix, true, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 text-danger" })
                            <label for="IsRemixYes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 pull-left text-danger">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsRemix, false, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 text-danger" })
                            <label for="IsRemixNo">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4 pull-left text-danger" for="SongTitle">Contains Sample</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="admin-form theme-primary">
                        <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 mr10 pull-left">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ContainsSample, true, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 text-danger" })
                            <label for="ContainsSampleYes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 pull-left">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ContainsSample, false, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 text-danger" })
                            <label for="ContainsSampleNo">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

I have tried to added a class, but it did not change the colour, I am using a theme and dont want to modify the theme css. Is it possible to use JQuery?

This is my CSS:

```
.radio-custom.radio-primary input[type=radio]:checked + label:after,
.radio-custom.radio-primary input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after,
.checkbox-custom.checkbox-primary input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after,
.checkbox-custom.checkbox-primary input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
  background-color: #4ea5e0;
  color: #4ea5e0;
}
.checkbox-custom.fill.checkbox-primary label:before {
  background-color: #4ea5e0;
}
```

Comment: use `!important` in your costume css to override the bootstrap default color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery quite easily. I'm presuming that the checkbox will be some kind of pseudo-checkbox to allow the styling, so you may need to be very specific on the selector and the styling (looking at existing css and in the browser inspector will help with that), but to change the styling, you can use jQuery on the page:

```
$(function () {
    $(".radio-custom").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

If you are over-riding `css` that is set as `!important` in `css`, you can use this approach which accepts a third priority parameter:

```
$(function () {
    $('.radio-custom').each(function () {
        this.style.setProperty('background-color', 'yellow', 'important');
    });
});
```

Comment: I have added the styling from the theme.css

Comment: @Rob - updated in case the css you are trying to over-ride is set as !important - this really should work if you are selecting the correct element property (which can get involved for radio buttons) and setting the correct css attribute